# Rename the folders in a directory in consecutive numbers

Tags: shell, unix

I have a directory which contains folders as follows :

```
filexyzwd1
filexyghj12
file_sghgjhgj3
file_gjhghjg
```

I want to rename the folders as shown below :

```
1
2
3
4
```

I have tried the following code:

```
i=1; for dir in */; do mv "$dir" i;i=$(( i + 1 )); done
```

which gives me the below output:

```
2 
i
```

Comment: `$i+1` doesn't change the value of `i`. Try `i=$(( i + 1 ))` or `let i++`. See

Comment: -bash: i++: command not found

Comment: I suggest reading my comment a second time and then trying what I *actually* suggested. Good luck!

Comment: I tried both;but it is suggesting me error.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the help.This time it worked but the result is shown in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script after some fixing could look like this:

```
i=1; for dir in */; do mv "$dir" "$i"; i=$((i + 1)); done
```

NoteS:

- There is no `$` in front of assignments. Don't `$i=1` do `i=1`.
- `i++` tries to run a command named `i++`. To do arithmetic calculations use arithmetic expansion `$(( .. ))` and store the output somewhere.

Comment: `i=$((i + 1))`  will also work simply as just: `((i++))`

Comment: @user3439894 Yes and one should note that the `(( .. ))` arithmetic expressions is a bash extension. Arithmetic expansion `$(( ... ))` is posix.